# Autocomplete não funciona - Asp .net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, autocompletar

Bom dia pessoal, estou com problemas para implementar um campo com autocomplete em uma aplicação Asp .Net MVC. O problema é o seguinte, utilizando um Ajax eu consigo ir até o meu controller e buscar resultados da consulta, porem, na volta onde deve exibir o resultado ele sempre cai no campo de "erro", mostrando Json em um "alert" como vou mostrar logo abaixo:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Cd_Cod_Produto').keypress(function () {
        $('#Cd_Cod_Produto').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Estoque/GetAutoComplete",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "application/json",
                    data: { term: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.Name,
                                value: item.Value                                  
                            }
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }                   
                });
            }
        });

    });

});
```

Como podem ver, caso ocorra algum erro, é exibido um alert com o resultado da busca, e sempre cai nesse alert. O meu Controller está dessa forma:

```
 public ActionResult GetAutoComplete(string term)
    {
        EstoqueDAO dao = new EstoqueDAO();

        List<Autocomplete> lista = dao.BuscaResultados(term);

        dao.Dispose();

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lista);

        return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

e este é o modelo que estou utilizando apenas para teste:

```
 public class Autocomplete
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

}
```

A busca no banco de dados está retornando valores corretamente, acredito que não seja o problema. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver na imagem é o que acontece com o retorno da função. Alguem tem alguma dica ou sugestão de onde eu estou errando? Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Atenciosamente,

Atualização:

Mudei o script para está forma:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Cd_Cod_Produto').keypress(function () {
        $('#Cd_Cod_Produto').autocomplete({
            source: function () {
                $.get(url, { term: $('#Cd_Cod_Produto').val() }, function (data) {
                    $.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.Name,
                            val: item.Value

                            //console.log(item.Name);

                        }                              
                    });

                });
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Desse jeito ele busca os resultados no controller, mas ainda não exibi nada no autocomplete. Se retirar os comentarios da linha "//console.log(item.Name)" ele exibi os resultados no console normalmente.

Comment: Retira esse trecho de código `string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lista);` e retorna assim: `return Json(lista, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: Olá @PedroPaulo, obrigado por responder. fiz o que você falou, mas continua caindo no alert, a diferença é que o Json retornado ficou desta forma: [{"Name":"ES001","Value":"ES001"},{"Name":"ES002","Value":"ES002"},{"Name":"ES003","Value":"ES003"},{"Name":"ES004","Value":"ES004"}]...sem os "\" como estava sendo exibido anteriormente.

Comment: Outra observação, esse método deveria ser `GET`, semanticamente faz mais sentido. Até o nome do seu método no back-end começa com `Get`.

Comment: @Pedro Paulo, eu troquei os métodos para ficar mais semântico, mas o problema continua.

Answer (score 0):

mude essa parte:

```
 function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.Label,
                                value: item.Value                                  
                            }
                        }))
```

para:

```
function (data) {
 $.map(data, function (item) {
  return {
       label: item['Name'],
       value: item['Value']   
      //ou
      //label: item.Name,
      //value: item.Value                                 
   }
   }
```

Exemplo funcional:

```js
var lis = [{'Name': '1', 'Value': 'A'}, {'Name': '2', 'Value': 'B'}, {'Name': '3', 'Value': 'C'}, {'Name': '4', 'Value': 'D'}];


var x = $.map(lis, function(item){
     return {
       label: item.Name,
      value: item.Value                              
   }
});

console.log(x);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: obrigado pela sua resposta, foi um erro de uma tentativa anterior, já mudei para "Name" e continua não funcionando.

Comment: @Q.Wesley alterei a resposta.

Comment: eu fiz as mudanças que você falou, não deu certo, continua caindo no alert.

Comment: poderia testar o retorno somente do Data, algo assim function (data) { return data;}

Comment: e para ter certeza do resultado crie um var para receber o ajax, e depois use no source

Comment: eu fiz os teste que você pediu, peguei o retorno do ajax e joguei em uma variável, e pedi para exibir o valor no console e em um "alert", o resultado foi "undefined" nos dois casos. o codigo que usei foi esse:

Comment: function testAjax() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Estoque/GetAutoComplete",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "application/json",
            data: { term: '00' },
            success: function (data) {
                return data;
            }
        });
    };

    function Teste() {
        var retorno = testAjax();
        alert(retorno);
        console.log(retorno);
    };

Comment: vc esqueceu o return aqui function testAjax() { return $.ajax...

Comment: coloque um breakpoint no console web e veja se os dados estao chegando na variavel.

Comment: eu fiz uma outra função, modifiquei algumas coisa, ficou dessa forma:
 function testAjax() {
        var url = "/Estoque/GetAutoComplete";

        $.get(url, { term: '00' }, function (data) {

            //console.log(data);

            $.map(data, function (item) {

                console.log(item.Name);

            });

        });
    };
Desta forma consegui exibir no console os resultados.